# LongAdder vs Integer in Hash map for frequency map

Tags: java, java-8

I am constructing a frequency map in a single-threaded environment using a HashMap. The keys are the Strings whose frequencies needs to be tracked.

If I use HashMap<String, Integer>, each increment needs a new Integer.

Would a LongAdder perform better for this use case as I can simply call increment()? Some rudimentary testing showed that LongAdder does indeed perform slightly better but I am not sure why.

Comment: That's for a multiple thread environment.   I can't see how that would be an improvement unless you have concurrency issues.

Comment: Yea and that's why i tried them out with 100 million additions. LongAdder was consistently twice as fast as Integer. I'm not sure why this is the case.

Comment: That depends on the number of map entries vs. the average number of increments per entry. Boxing vs. synchronization overhead. But you don’t need to pay the synchronization overhead. You can create your own object holding a mutable `int` field. Or use the common trick of using an `int[]` of length one, though the dedicated object with field may be slightly faster as it doesn’t need a range check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing to determine relative performance of incrementing integral types.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class LongAdderTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LongAdderTest().start();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        int N = 100_000_000;
        int warmup = 3;
        String[] testNames = { "LongAdder", "Long", "Integer", "long",
                "int", "Object", "int[]", "long[]" };
        List<Function<Integer, Long>> tests = List.of(
                this::longAdderTest, this::longWrapperTest,
                this::integerWrapperTest, this::primitiveLongTest,
                this::primitiveIntTest, this::objectTest,
                this::intArrayTest, this::longArrayTest);
        
        int i = 0;
        for (Function<Integer, Long> test : tests) {
            runTest(test, warmup, N, testNames[i++]);
        }
    }
    
    public void runTest(Function<Integer, Long> test, int warmup,
            int iterations, String testName) {
        // warmup cycle
        for (int i = 0; i < warmup; i++) {
            long v = test.apply(iterations);
            if (v != iterations) {
                System.out
                        .println("Unexpected result - return = " + v);
            }
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long val = test.apply(iterations);
        System.out.printf("%-10s : %12f  %d%n", testName,
                (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000., val);
    }
    
    public long longAdderTest(int iter) {
        LongAdder val = new LongAdder();
        Map<String, LongAdder> freq = new HashMap<>();
        freq.put("A", val);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.get("A").increment();
        }
        return freq.get("A").longValue();
    }
    
    public long longWrapperTest(int iter) {
        Long val = 0L;
        Map<String, Long> freq = new HashMap<>();
        freq.put("A", val);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.computeIfPresent("A", (k, v) -> v + 1);
        }
        return freq.get("A");
    }
    
    public long integerWrapperTest(int iter) {
        Integer val = 0;
        Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
        freq.put("A", val);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.computeIfPresent("A", (k, v) -> v + 1);
        }
        return freq.get("A");
    }
    
    public long primitiveLongTest(int iter) {
        Map<String, Long> freq = new HashMap<>();
        long val = 0;
        freq.put("A", val);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.computeIfPresent("A", (k, v) -> v + 1);
        }
        return freq.get("A");
    }
    
    public long primitiveIntTest(int iter) {
        Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
        int val = 0;
        freq.put("A", val);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.computeIfPresent("A", (k, v) -> v + 1);
        }
        return freq.get("A");
    }
    
    public long intArrayTest(int iter) {
        Map<String, int[]> freq = new HashMap<>();
        int[] val = { 0 };
        freq.put("A", val);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.get("A")[0] += 1;
        }
        return freq.get("A")[0];
    }
    
    public long longArrayTest(int iter) {
        Map<String, long[]> freq = new HashMap<>();
        long[] val = { 0L };
        freq.put("A", val);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.get("A")[0] += 1;
        }
        return freq.get("A")[0];
        
    }
    
    public long objectTest(int iter) {
        MyLongIncrement longObject = new MyLongIncrement(0);
        Map<String, MyLongIncrement> freq = new HashMap<>();
        freq.put("A", longObject);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            freq.get("A").increment();
        }
        return freq.get("A").get();
    }
    
    static class MyLongIncrement {
        long val;
        
        public MyLongIncrement(long v) {
            this.val = v;
        }
        
        public long get() {
            return val;
        }
        
        public void increment() {
            val += 1l;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample run.

```
LongAdder  :  4166.724472  100000000
Long       :  2929.021352  100000000
Integer    :  5487.358323  100000000
long       :  2993.538570  100000000
int        :  2505.171838  100000000
Object     :  1032.322116  100000000
int[]      :  1132.710126  100000000
long[]     :  1107.633331  100000000
```

Details

- Using a Map brought the values closer.  Imo, too close to make a definitive call.
- But it would seem that incrementing in place with the last three types might be best since the value itself does not have to be updated in the map.  Same for the `LongAdder` but the synchronization code could be a factor (or the test designer) for its less than stellar performance.  But then, there could be many factors including my method of accessing the map value.

I think I'm done with this. Hope it shed some light on the issue.

Comment: For a starter, put each test into an individual method, call these methods multiple times for warmup and then measure their execution time. It’s also worth testing them in separate runtimes, e.g. let the main program take a parameter, telling which method to test. Though I don’t think that it matters much in this case. But mind that the OP used the increment operation in the context of a `HashMap` value update which may take more time than the entire increment. Using plain `int` is not an option then, but an `int[]` with length one would do (or a dedicated object with a mutable `int` field).

Comment: @holger  I took your advice and made some changes.  The test class should run as is.  Please note the anomalies at the end of the post.

Comment: In the best case, the optimizer detects that you are not using the sum. You could change the methods to return the sum and then do something with it, e.g. `if(sum != expectedValue) throw …`. But even then, an optimizer may recognize that you are performing *n* increments which can be replaced by just returning the value *n*. If you want to be closer to the OPs scenario, use a `Map` and truly increment its values. And move the redundant time measuring code to the caller…

Comment: Did you consider using [JMH](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness) it's pretty standard for these type of benchmarks.

Comment: @matt in an earlier post I said I didn't have it installed.  But it is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Now that’s closer to the expectation. Note that you can’t store a primitive value in a `HashMap` directly, hence, `long` and `Long` do exactly the same, which explains the close numbers. The same should apply to `int` and `Integer`, so the difference is a sign that something’s wrong. Perhaps, garbage collection took place.

Comment: Any idea why Integer took almost twice as much time as Long?

Comment: Nope.  I would have expected the opposite.  It could be the way I organized the tests.  This is probably why testing this way is not the best.  JMH would be preferable.  But even then the results need to be properly interpreted.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab as said, `int` and `Integer` actually do the same. And when you compare the results of `int`, `long`, and `Long`, they’re plausible. The result of `Integer` is an outlier.